# how to store gmail profile picture in session?

Tags: php, session, oauth

I had perform login via gmail using OAuth. now i want to display user's name and profile photo in my header. once i had achieve this by passing these values from controller to my view now in my another views i also want that name and photo i had try to store those 2 values in session i got success in name but not in image.
so, how to achieve this?? or is there any another way for this??

Controller :

```
$email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$img = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
$name = $user['name'];
$data=array('name'=>$name,'image'=>$img,'email'=>$email);
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

view :

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('name'); ?>
<img class="login" src="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('image'); ?>" alt=" " style="border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%; height: 60px; width: 60px"/>
```

Comment: you can store imageUrl in session no need of storing whole image in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have store an whole image in session you just have to store an imageUrl in session and you can use that session value in any other view hope this will help you.